# Maas cannot power control virsh node

Tags: maas

Maas is not able to power-control vm-nodes.
If i try to commission a declared vm node with the power settings:

- Power address: qemu+ssh://ubuntu@192.168.25.14/system
- Power id: vm1

the node does not start, but performing

```
virsh -c qemu+ssh://ubuntu@192.168.25.14/system start vm1
```

in the terminal works fine.
I checked in the host node, all ssh keys are there the key of my user, the juju-client-key and the juju-system-key.

Comment: Does the virsh command work when using the maas account , are the ssh keys setup correctly from there. I had problems when the power id was incorrect.

Comment: i think thats the key to the problem, i does not have a 'maas' account. I didn't use the maas installation routine, but I installed maas using repos on a clean ubuntu 14.04 server installation using my user account.

Comment: Ok solved my problem. I had to add a 'maas' user on my maasmaster, generate an ssh-key for it and finally add this key to all the hosts. That was already done, but i had to clear all old host-addresses from .ssh/knownhosts on my maas-master. This could block virsh -c qemu+ssh://... to connect and you would not get any traceback or error report.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution in the answer section below ? That way it will be easier for future readers to find it